# Rake tasks prompt insecure writable dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rake

when i trying to perform any of `rake` command it will so me this error

```
shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/android-sdk/tools in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.1.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/examples/demo_app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/examples/demo_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/examples/demo_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/examples/demo_app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/examples/demo_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/examples/demo_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

help me solve this thank you.

Comment: just run `bundle update`

Comment: I would run `bundle update rake` so you're only explicitly updating rake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bundle exec rake your_task_name
```

Comment: @P_M Not sure what do you mean by **temporary solution**, this is a solution when you have to keep multiple version of gem installed in your system because of multiple project dependency. You have to run tasks in context of your current project using `bundle exec` without breaking any other dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes up when your `Gemfile.lock` has different versions of the gems installed on your machine. A warning comes up as :

`You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.1.1. Prepending`bundle exec`to your command may solve this.`

Adding `bundle exec` forces bundler to run the command ignoring difference of version.

Fortunately, there is a gem that solves this: rubygems-bundler.

```
> gem install rubygems-bundler

> gem regenerate_binstubs
```

After this try your rake commands it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove particular version of rake

with command of  `gem uninstall rake`

and it will allow you to run `rake` command